# if $b_j>0$ and $\sum b_j$ converges . prove that $\sum \frac{\sqrt{b_j}}{j^\alpha}$ converge for $\alpha>1/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$b_j>0$
and $\sum b_j$
converges 
. prove that $\sum \frac{\sqrt{b_j}}{j^\alpha}$ converge for $\alpha>1/2$.

I know that $\sum \sqrt{b_j}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{j^{2\alpha}}$ converge. O just don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Also, your claim "I know that $\sum \sqrt{b_j}$ and [...] converge" is interesting, because the statement is most certainly false. (Without the square root, maybe?)